# Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout Vertical layout with horizontal paging/scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

```
-----------------------------------
1 2 3 4 |  9 10 11 12 | 17 18 19 20
5 6 7 8 | 13 14 15 16 | 21 22 23 24
-----------------------------------
 Page 1      Page 2        Page 3
```

I currently have a working layout but it gets messed up on larger screens (6 plus).

Screenshots: [All other devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs9cg.png) & [iphone 6+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqF3H.png)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TagCollectionLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger nbColumns;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger nbLines;

@end
```

and

```
#import "TagCollectionLayout.h"

@implementation TagCollectionLayout

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        self.nbColumns = -1;
        self.nbLines = -1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger nbColumns = self.nbColumns != -1 ? self.nbColumns : (int)(self.collectionView.frame.size.width / self.itemSize.width);
    NSInteger nbLines = self.nbLines != -1 ? self.nbLines : (int)(self.collectionView.frame.size.height / self.itemSize.height);

    NSInteger idxPage = (int)indexPath.row/(nbColumns * nbLines);

    NSInteger O = indexPath.row - (idxPage * nbColumns * nbLines);

    NSInteger xD = (int)(O / nbColumns);
    NSInteger yD = O % nbColumns;

    NSInteger D = xD + (yD * nbLines) + (idxPage * nbColumns * nbLines);

    NSIndexPath *fakeIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:D inSection:indexPath.section];

    return [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:fakeIndexPath];
}

-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat newX = MIN(0, rect.origin.x - rect.size.width/2);
    CGFloat newWidth = rect.size.width*2 + (rect.origin.x - newX);

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(newX, rect.origin.y, newWidth, rect.size.height);

    // Get all the attributes for the elements in the specified frame
    NSArray *allAttributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:newRect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr in allAttributesInRect) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newAttr = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:attr.indexPath];
        attr.frame = newAttr.frame;
        attr.center = newAttr.center;
        attr.bounds = newAttr.bounds;
        attr.hidden = newAttr.hidden;
        attr.size = newAttr.size;
    }
    return allAttributesInRect;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Do you guys have any ideas on why the larger screens have this weird issue?

Comment: It seems your nbColumns and nbLines formulae is having some calculation issue

Comment: You should vary your nbColumns and nbLines variables according to your screen size

Comment: @HarshIT any ideas to a solution where i lays out the items in a vertical fashion but pages horizontally? It doesn't have to be what I have above.

Comment: can you show your exact value of  nbColumns & nbLines variables. It seems quite easy to solve the problem.

Comment: @HarshIT I was creating a 4 by 3 grid. nbColumns = 4 & nbLines = 3

Comment: and what is your cell size (width,height) ?

Comment: let size = self.collectionView.frame.size.width/4 - 15;

Comment: self.layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(size, size)